# Ubuntu - getting GPS coordinates from dongle (bu-353)

Tags: ubuntu, gps, gpsd

I am trying to get longitude and latitude coordinates from a GPS dongle I have here (BU-353).
I have installed gpsd and gpsmon.

Gpsmon correctly show my location and updates it. 
Whenever I run this command:

```
sudo gpsd -n -N -D 2 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I get this output:

```
gpsd: launching (Version 2.95)
gpsd: listening on port gpsd
gpsd: running with effective group ID 0
gpsd: running with effective user ID 0
gpsd: opening GPS data source type 3 at '/dev/ttyUSB0'
gpsd: speed 9600, 8N1
gpsd: attempting USB device enumeration.
gpsd: 1d6b:0001 (bus 1, device 1)
gpsd: 80ee:0021 (bus 1, device 2)
gpsd: 067b:2303 (bus 1, device 3)
gpsd: vendor/product match with 091e:0003 not found
gpsd: speed 9600, 8O1
gpsd: speed 9600, 8N1
gpsd: gpsd_activate(): opened GPS (fd 6)
gpsd: speed 4800, 8N1
gpsd: NTPD ntpd_link_activate: 1
gpsd: /dev/ttyUSB0 identified as type SiRF binary (1.497303 sec @ 4800bps)
gpsd: GPS on /dev/ttyUSB0 is offline (0.000016 sec since data)
gpsd: GPS on /dev/ttyUSB0 is offline (0.000017 sec since data)
gpsd: GPS on /dev/ttyUSB0 is offline (0.000565 sec since data)
gpsd: GPS on /dev/ttyUSB0 is offline (0.000018 sec since data)
gpsd: GPS on /dev/ttyUSB0 is offline (0.000019 sec since data)
```

And clearly isn't working.

**My goal** is to be able to have a script which keeps returning something like:

XX.XXXXX N, XX,XXXXX E

So, that I can read it from another program (in Erlang) and use it accordingly.

More info:

**Xgps** works correctly.

I believe the speed '9600' might be incorrect and something with the vendor ID, not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, I'm using BU-353 on Angstrom:

Change from binary to NMEA:

```
$ gpsctl -f -n /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Configuration of serial port:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 ispeed 4800
```

If you want to keep NMEA, then type just -b flag:

```
$ gpsd -b /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Output id shown with this:

```
$ cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Hope it helps! You have to write sudo in front of lines.